# GWT ant devmode:ant is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: gwt

I am following GWT [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html) from code.google.com. I build an application using webAppCreator & try to run it from command line using ant devmode. It raises this error, *ant is not recognized as an internal or external command*

Comment: "ant is not recognized as an internal or external command": in other words: you might need to install Ant before using it! But really, use Eclipse, as suggested by tim_a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the eclipse plugin. You can download eclipse for free by clicking [here](http://www.eclipse.org/)
Then click "help" and "install new software". Enter this link: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6
Just click next, next and restart eclipse. 
If you really want to use the command line you should add your sdk path to your computer variables but I don't know the exact setup anymore.

Comment: thank you very much tim_a. I already have had plugin installed for eclipse but not ant. as I never used ant not this tutorial was referring to install it when at this point.